Why does setTimeout() not accept _.run() as a function?
I have this following nodejs code which did not work
const _ = {}

_.run = () => {
  ...
}

setTimeout(_.run(), 1000);

What worked was setTimeout( () => { _.run() }, 1000);
I'm not sure why since _.run() is also a function that setTimeout ought to accept.
Any ideas why and where should I look at?

_.run() calls the function, and then the return value of that function is used as the first argument to setTimeout (the first argument should be a function reference, which I doubt your run function is returning).

Ie, do setTimeout(_.run, 1000) instead

Forget callbacks for a moment. Say you have two functions: x = (i) => console.log(i) and y = () => 5. If you do x(y()) in any language, be it PHP, C++, javascript, Pascal etc. do you expect it to print 5 or Function? Obviously you expect 5 because y() returns 5, not itself.

I got it now! I really need to revise my JS! Thanks chaps!
